# How to add a action to NSButton by code

Tags: macos, nsbutton

I know you can add action to UIButton like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selecter(mySelector:) onControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But how do you do it for OS X NSButton?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, you can do this:

```
[button setAction:@selector(mySelector)];
```